# Trimmed vertical cell line in table to clarify cells with linebreaks

Tags: tables

I need to add vertical lines in front of cells with line breaks to clarify which row the contents of the large cell correspond to.
However, these lines must not span the full cell height because if two consecutive cells have line breaks, the line will touch.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

% to make specific-length columns
\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedright}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\centering}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedleft}m{#1}}

% example:  C{0.5\textwidth}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[]
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{@{}lL{0.2\textwidth}llrlllllllllll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Stuff} & \textbf{Other stuff} & 4.B & 4.D & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5} & 5.A & 5.B & 5.D & 5.E & 5.F \\ \midrule
This text & short text &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{DC7878}15 &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDA9A9}7} &  &  &   \\
That text & Some longer text that splits &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{F1BDBD}3 &  &  &  &  &    \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC} 
Red text & Even loooonger text that splits, maybe even more than once &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{F1BDBD}3 &  &  &  &  &   \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC} 
Blue text & Some long text once again that splits &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{F1BDBD}3 &  &  &  &  &   \\
Up text & blah blah blah, again text here &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} \\
Down text & text. &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which makes the following table:

[image: table 1]

My current guess is to use `multicol` to add the line separation, but as mentioned above, this connects consecutive vertical lines like below, which I do not want.

[image: table 2]

Code for table with multicol lines:

```
\begin{table}[]
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{@{}lL{0.2\textwidth}llrlllllllllll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Stuff} & \textbf{Other stuff} & 4.B & 4.D & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5} & 5.A & 5.B & 5.D & 5.E & 5.F \\ \midrule
This text & short text &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{DC7878}15 &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDA9A9}7} &  &  &    \\
That text & \multicolumn{1}{|L{0.2\textwidth}}{Some longer text that splits} &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{F1BDBD}3 &  &  &  &  &  \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC} 
Red text & \multicolumn{1}{|L{0.2\textwidth}}{Even loooonger text that splits, maybe even more than once} &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{F1BDBD}3 &  &  &  &  &   \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC} 
Blue text & Some text &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{F1BDBD}3 &  &  &  &  &    \\
Up text & \multicolumn{1}{|L{0.2\textwidth}}{blah blah blah, again text here} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  &  \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} \\
Down text & text. &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How can I have shorter vertical lines ?

Disclaimer: I know vertical lines are the devil (hence, booktabs).
I'm up for suggestions if you have better ideas to clarify line separation while having some rows with specific background colors in page-long tables...

Comment: Have you considered `\midrule` between every row? Or does that not fit with your aesthetics of the colored background?

Comment: adding midrules makes the table very dense, and much harder to read given that much of the cells in the numbered columns are actually empty. I would just have added padding between the rows if the table was not so long to begin with (it needs to fit on 1 page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can always draw whatever rule you want by using TikZ in the `\CodeAfter` and the PGF/TikZ nodes creates by `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% to make specific-length columns
\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedright}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\centering}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedleft}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}lL{0.2\textwidth}llrlllll@{}}[color-inside]
\toprule
\textbf{Stuff} & \textbf{Other stuff} & 4.B & 4.D & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5} & 5.A & 5.B & 5.D & 5.E & 5.F \\ \midrule
This text & short text &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{DC7878}15 &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDA9A9}7} &  &  &   \\
That text & Some longer text that splits &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{F1BDBD}3 &  &  &  &  &    \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC} 
Red text & Even loooonger text that splits, maybe even more than once &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{F1BDBD}3 &  &  &  &  &   \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC} 
Blue text & Some long text once again that splits &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{F1BDBD}3 &  &  &  &  &   \\
Up text & blah blah blah, again text here &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} \\
Down text & text. &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}1} \\
\bottomrule
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [shorten < = 2pt, shorten > = 2pt]
    \draw (3-|2) -- (4-|2) ; 
    \draw (4-|2) -- (5-|2) ;
    \draw (5-|2) -- (6-|2) ;
    \draw (6-|2) -- (7-|2) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

However, there is a small problem because `nicematrix` does not apply the instructions for the colors which are in the tabular in the same order that `colortbl`. By using instructions in the `\CodeBefore`, there is no problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
% nicematrix provides the column m[l]{...}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}lm[l]{0.2\textwidth}llrlllll@{}}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC}{4,5}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{EDA9A9}{2-7}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{DC7878}{2-5}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{F3C7C7}{3-5,4-5,5-5,6-8,7-8,6-10,7-10}
\Body
\toprule
\textbf{Stuff} & \textbf{Other stuff} & 4.B & 4.D & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5} & 5.A & 5.B & 5.D & 5.E & 5.F \\ \midrule
This text & short text &  &  & 15 &  &  \multicolumn{1}{r}{7} &  &  &   \\
That text & Some longer text that splits &  &  & 3 &  &  &  &  &    \\
Red text & Even loooonger text that splits, maybe even more than once &  &  & 3 &  &  &  &  &   \\
Blue text & Some long text once again that splits &  &  & 3 &  &  &  &  &   \\
Up text & blah blah blah, again text here &  &  & &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1} &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1} \\
Down text & text. &  &  & &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1} &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1}\\
\bottomrule
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [shorten < = 2pt, shorten > = 2pt]
    \draw (3-|2) -- (4-|2) ; 
    \draw (4-|2) -- (5-|2) ;
    \draw (5-|2) -- (6-|2) ;
    \draw (6-|2) -- (7-|2) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I didn't have trouble with the red colors, so I didn't need your workaround (which would have been a definitive no for your solution otherwise given the size of the actual table).